# Get JSON data with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

To access specific JSON data i need to access `Main -> Listing -> c44 -> Mydata`

`c44` is dynamic and can be anything. 
I have it in my variable - `var cc`

To access needed data, i write: 
`var result = Main.listing. * how can i specify cc var here? *`

Tried `console.log (main.listing.["cc"]);` but never worked

Comment: you want `main.listing[cc]`

Comment: @JaromandaX Worked! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `cc` is a variable, you should remove the quotes `"`. Try:

`console.log (main.listing[cc]);`

Answer (score 0):

You can access the data using

```
Main.Listing[cc]
```